# Connection timed out error in Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-lambda

I am trying to SSH all the ec2 instances in AWS account through lambda function.

c.connect( hostname = each_in.private_ip_address, username = 'pcs_user', pkey = k )

But I'm getting an error like this. I have used AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole to IAM role.

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 110] Connection timed out",
  "errorType": "TimeoutError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 30, in lambda_handler\n    c.connect( hostname = each_in.private_ip_address, username = 'pcs_us', pkey = k )\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/client.py\", line 349, in connect\n    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/util.py\", line 283, in retry_on_signal\n    return function()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/paramiko/client.py\", line 349, in <lambda>\n    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: 2 questions, is the Lambda in the VPC and have you whitelisted the Lambda IP range(s) in your security groups?

Comment: @Chris Williams Since I need to access all the ec2 instances in the AWS account I didn't specify a VPC to lambda function. I just added the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole to IAM role.

Comment: That role only grants permission for the LAmbda function to manage its ENI, but for that to take place it needs to be in a VPC to function :)

Comment: Since I need to access all the EC2 instances in the AWS account is there any way to select all the VPC's together.

Comment: The suggestion would be to create a VPC for the Lambda and attach a transit gateway to allow the Lambda VPC to speak to all of the VPCs. Otherwise you will need to have every instance be public and whitelist an IP range that changes frequently. The answer describes how to add to a VPC.

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the Lambda is unable to connect to your EC2 instances due to a security group rule blocking access.

If you are trying to connect to EC2 instances in your account you should [add your Lambda to your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) by attaching it via VPC configuration, it should be added into private subnets.

Once your Lambdas are added to your VPC, whitelist in your security group of the instances allowing the IP range(s) of the subnet(s) in which your Lambda resides.

By doing this you are stopping any access from traversing the public internet. Ensure your Lambda connects to any VPCs via their private IP address. For any instances outside your VPC you will need to use peering either via [Transit Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/) or a [peering connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html).

**If** you cannot have your Lambda in a VPC then you will need to maintain a whitelist in the security group of each instance to whitelist the Lambda public range from the [ip-ranges.json](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) file. This must be for the range of the Lambda service in the region it has been deployed to.